# Phone is stuck on "downloading... do not turn off"

Tags: samsung, external-sd, odin

My phone is stuck: has the green bot and reads  downloading... Do not turn off. Target.

Top right reads 
{odin3}
Product: amazing3gtrf
Version: s738cwyamj1
Custom binary: Samsung official
System status: Official

I was trying to do a SD test app and phone froze.

It's been like that for about two hours. Will it ever work or what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still in that mode (It's called download mode) you should hold your power button till your phone reboots.
Download is a mode where you can flash ROM's etc to your phone.